# How do i get my subdomain for this azure configuration to my android application

Tags: java, android, azure

This is the basic code for window azure configuration

```
 package com.msdpe.mymobileservice;

 public class Constants {
 public static final String kGetTodosUrl = "https://yoursubdomain.azure-   mobile.net/tables/TodoItem?$filter=(complete%20eq%20false)";
public static final String kAddTodoUrl =  "https://yoursubdomain.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem";
public static final String kUpdateTodoUrl = "https://yoursubdomain.azure-         mobile.net/tables/TodoItem/";
public static final String kMobileServiceAppId =  "myappkey";

}
```

I can obtain my appkey from my mobile service in the window azure. According to the tutorial, they ask me to replace the 3 URL, but how do i get my subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subdomain is the name of the Mobile Service you created.  You can also view the full URL of your Mobile Service by going to the Dashboard for your Mobile Service in the Windows Azure Portal and looking on the right side.

Comment: you mean mobile server url ? is it the same for all the 3 option, kGetTodosUrl, kAddTodoUrl, kUpdateTodoUrl?

Comment: Yes, https://yourmobileserviceurl/tables/....  So if you created a Mobile Service named "mymobileservice", you would use url: https://mymobileservice.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem to access the TodoItem table.